# Wait for 1 promise and then all promises using $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise, q

I'm fairly familiar with how `$q` works and I use it in angularjs to wait for single promises to resolve and multiple promises to resolve with `$q.all()`.

The question is I'm not sure if its possible to do this (and if it works correctly): Can I wait for a single promise to resolve, but then also run some code when all my promises resolve too... AFTER the success callbacks of the individual promises have finished... for example:

```
var promises = [];
for(i=1, i<5, i++){
    var singlePromise = SomeSevice.getData();
    promises.push(singlePromise);
    singlePromise.then(function(data){
         console.log("This specific promise resolved");
    });
}


// note: its important that this runs AFTER the code inside the success 
//  callback of the single promise runs ....
$q.all(promises).then(function(data){
    console.log("ALL PROMISES NOW RESOLVED"); // this code runs when all promises also resolved
});
```

My question is, does this work as I think it does, or is there some weird async, indeterministic result risk?

Comment: Hi @lonesomeday, I have made a small change to my question; the primary requirement is that the all() callback runs after the success callback of the individual promises finishes!

Comment: I saw that and deleted my comment because it was no longer relevant.

Comment: So your question is actually if the `.all` callback is always fired **after** the last `singlePromise.then` callback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A call to `then` also returns a promise. You can then pass this to your array instead of the original promise. This way your `$q.all` will run after all your `then`s have been executed.

```
var promises = [];
for(i=1, i<5, i++){
    // singlePromise - this is now a new promise from the resulting then
    var singlePromise = SomeSevice.getData().then(function(data){
         console.log("This specific promise resolved");
    });
    promises.push(singlePromise);
}

$q.all(promises).then(function(data){
    console.log("ALL PROMISES NOW RESOLVED");
});
```

Comment: This sounds brilliant - I will try it out.

Comment: If a promise fail, all chain promise stops, but if you put catch in individual promise, the chain promise continue, and each promise with catch will be return undefined in array index of promise.all.

Comment: @RafaelDantas - good point. It's not that I did not consider it but more that I felt it was out of scope for the question. The OP should definitely consider it in their final code to ensure the code is fault tolerant.